# Action when form is closed

Tags: c#

How to make as by pressing to the close button, make so that the form was not closed, and it was turned off?

```
private void Form1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.Hide();
}
```

So the form is all the same closed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should do it on FormClosing not FormClosed event like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Form1.Hide();
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

FormClosed means the form is already closed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to interrupt the form closing event and cancel it, for example to minimize:

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
   this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Comment: Minimized will make it stay, just in minimized form.

Comment: @MadBoy - Agreed, but the question was unclear, and this is the most common scenario...that or sending to the tray, so just throwing this option out there.

Answer (score 1):

see [**Form.Closing Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)

Here is the sample. you have several options

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  // this.Hide();
  // e.Cancel = true;
  this.Close();           

}
```

> to remove a form both from the
>   display, and from memory, it is
>   necessary to Close rather than Hide it

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FormClosing` event, and set `e.Cancel` to true.