# Action on Form Close? C#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm Hunting the Wumpus, and I've run into an issue. (I'm a high-schooler)
I'm in charge of the Trivia Class, and I'm doing something wrong here.
In my current code, I'm displaying a form, asking the user for an input, and setting the answerstatus as true/false. I want another class to count the number of answer correct based on the given answer. My question is, how do I get this class to count, when the user closes the window?

```
public void passOrFailWumpusEncounter(bool result)
{
    if (currentTested == WUMPUS_TEST_AMOUNT)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(result)
    {
        currentPassed++;
        currentTested++;
    }
    else
    {
        currentTested++;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the "result" from

```
public bool getQuestionStatus()
{
    return questionStatus;
}
```

(on another class)
I've tried

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    trivia.passOrFailWumpusEncounter(prompt.getQuestionStatus());
}
```

But it doesn't do anything on close!

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# - action when form is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261179/c-sharp-action-when-form-is-closed), almost word for word in the title. Please search for possible solutions before posting a question; it cuts down on noise and duplication. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think you might need to include a little more code.  There's no logical relationship between the two snippets you have posted.

Comment: Done, the 3rd snippet is the actual attempt at closing it.

Comment: I'm curious--did you add this `FormClosing` event from the designer, or did you just write the method because you saw it in an example somewhere?

Comment: have you tried breakpointing the form closing to check it is being hit? is currentPassed and currentTested static or instance (i.e could you accidently be setting them back to 0 each time?)

Comment: I wrote it from an example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well, what you want is to run some code (that will count something) when the user closes the window?

Programmatically, you should run at init (for instance when the form is loaded)

```
form1.Close += ANewFunction;  // registering the handler
```

And write the handler itself:

```
public void ANewFunction(EventsArg e)   { ... }
```

But in such a simple case, you should let Visual Studio do the dirty job: in the forms properties, double click on teh Close event (you may need to click a button on the properties tab to show the events, and it will register the handler in form1.designer.cs and create the prototype of the handler close to your user code.

Comment: Simply writing "Form1_FormClosing" is not enough for making the code run. You need to register the handler on the event using "form1.Close += ANewFunction;"

Comment: It won't let me immediately mark it, done now though.

Answer (score 0):

Find any event that listens to the form closing. Make a handler, write code that calls a method in the other class that sets the number of correct answers. If this is undetailed, make your question more detailed please...

Comment: This doesn't answer my question... You've told me what i know..

Comment: @Ben, in that case you need to become better at writing your questions.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the form and showing it, it is still a live. So you can read the answer from that form in the calling function.

For example:

```
Form myForm = new Form();
myForm.ShowDialog();
if (myForm.CheckBox.Checked) //myForm still exists and you check it's state
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("The answer is yes!");
}
```